# Show notifications on Screen in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

i am using this code for sending local notifications

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int)value, mBuilder.build());
```

However they display on status bar if phone screen is lock by sliding. I want to show the push notifications on top of screen like whatsapp, facebook, sms messages etc.

How can I make this possible?

Comment: I think Android OS handle it automatically

Comment: @HirenPatel well no i am getting only small icon on status bar not showing on lock screen top

Comment: only in android 5 (lolipop) support heads up notifycation by default. so if yo still want do that then you can build custome notifycation view and add it into screen with windowmanager service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this way:

By adding below line:

```
setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
```

**Full code**:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify((int)value, mBuilder.build());
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working i am getting only top notification and notification on

Comment: it works for me but in marshmallow and above, thanks @Hiren